# Speed up Mootools accordion

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, transition

I am using the Mootools accordion for a project and would like to speed up the transitions. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `duration` option inherited from the mootools Fx class. So, your initializer might look like this:

```
var myAccordion = new Fx.Accordion(togglers, elements, { duration: 250 });
```

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Accordion

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx